# Get all accounts linked to a certain account (via IP)

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

### DB tables

I have two tables:

- the `account` table, having `id` and `username` fields (and other non-relevant fields - [account table full structure](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/data/sql/base/db_auth/account.sql)).
- the `account_ip` table, having `account` and `ip` fields (and other non-relevant fields - [account_ip table full structure](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-ip-tracker/blob/master/sql/auth/base/account_ip.sql)).

Their relation is:

- the `account_ip.account` field links with `account.id`.

The purpose of the `account_ip` table is

- keeping track of all IPs that each account has been successfully logged in with.

### Account IP linking

Convention:

- we say that two accounts are **linked** if they have an IP in common in the `account_ip` table

For example:

[image: account IP linking]

in this case the account `12` is linked to `13` because they have `127.0.0.1` in common, and the account `13` is linked to `14` because they have `127.0.0.4` in common:

12 <-> 13 <-> 14

### Queries

I can run some [queries](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-ip-tracker/blob/master/README.md#usage), such as:

- Level 1: select all accounts/IPs linked to a given account ID 123

```sql
SELECT account.username, account_ip.* FROM account_ip 
INNER JOIN account ON account.id = account_ip.account
WHERE ip IN (
    SELECT ip FROM account_ip WHERE account = 123
);
```

- Level 2: select all accounts/IPs linked to all accounts linked to a given account ID 123

```sql
SELECT account.username, account_ip.* FROM account_ip INNER JOIN account ON account.id = account_ip.account
WHERE ip IN (
    SELECT ip FROM account_ip WHERE account IN (
        SELECT account FROM account_ip WHERE ip IN (
            SELECT ip FROM account_ip WHERE account = 123
        )
    )
);
```

but this last one only goes until 2 levels of linking.

### Question

Given an account ID, how can I get all accounts/IPs that are related to that account at any linking level?

For example if I have this linking relations:

12 <-> 13 <-> 14 <-> 15 <-> 16

Given the account `12`, I would like a query that gives me all the accounts and IPs of 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph traversal problem . . . which requires a recursive CTE.  It is tricky with two elements.  One method is:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select account, ip, cast(ip as char(1000)) as visited_ips, cast(account as char(1000)) as visited_accounts
      from accounts
      where account = 12
      union all
      select a.account, a.ip, concat_ws(',', cte.visited_ips, a.ip), concat_ws(',', cte.visited_accounts, a.account)
      from cte join
           accounts a
           on a.ip = cte.ip or a.account = cte.account
      where ((a.account = cte.account and find_in_set(a.ip, cte.visited_ips) = 0) or
             (a.ip = cte.ip and find_in_set(a.account, cte.visited_accounts) = 0) ) 
     )
select distinct ip
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7b5bbb29e808f7b551cdd1073d4f572) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: the table is `account` without final `s`, but even after fixing that issue I got `Unknown column 'account' in 'field list'`

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi . . . I added the db<>fiddle to show the code working.  You have working code to start with.  You can adjust it for your particular column and table names.  Your data model is much more complicated than you have in the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Gordon Linoff, this requires a recursive CTE. However, CTE is available on MySQL 8+. His solution is a way to go if your DB supports CTE.

With that said, I've managed to create a stored procedure to get the accounts and IP's.

The limitations are:

- It uses temporary tables - the script cannot run in parallel from the same session.
- It is not optimized for performance

```
DROP PROCEDURE if EXISTS find_linked_accounts;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE find_linked_accounts(account_id INT)
BEGIN
    
    SET @start_account_id = account_id;
    SET @last_data_count = 0;
    SET @data_count = 0;
    
        
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists linked_accounts;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists temp_linked_accounts;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE linked_accounts(
        `account` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `ip` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(`account`, `ip`)
    );
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_linked_accounts(
        `account` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `ip` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(`account`, `ip`)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO  linked_accounts
    SELECT account, ip 
    FROM account_ip
    WHERE account_ip.account = @start_account_id;
    
    REPEAT
        SET @last_data_count = @data_count;
        # insert all accounts connected to the previously found accounts in the temp_linked_accounts table
        INSERT INTO temp_linked_accounts
        SELECT distinct aip.account, aip.ip 
        FROM account_ip aip
        INNER JOIN linked_accounts la ON la.account = aip.account OR la.ip = aip.ip;
        
        INSERT INTO linked_accounts
        SELECT account, ip 
        FROM temp_linked_accounts
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE linked_accounts.account=linked_accounts.account;
        
        SET @data_count = (SELECT COUNT(account) FROM linked_accounts);
        DELETE FROM temp_linked_accounts;
        UNTIL @data_count = @last_data_count
    END REPEAT;
    
    SELECT * FROM linked_accounts;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists linked_accounts;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists temp_linked_accounts;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

To invoke the stored procedure, execute `call find_linked_accounts(account_id);` - substitute account_id with integer value, e.g. `call find_linked_accounts(12);`.

This script has been tested on the latest AzerothCore database (as of the time of writing), and the SQL script provided in the question.